# ViewState does not changing with MapView

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, viewstate

I'm currently trying to display an Mapview inside a sheet. The weird thing is, that the MapView is shown in the canvas. However in the Simulator it isn't updating the view. Can someone explain to me, what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my **MapViewModel**

```
class MapViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    enum ViewState {
        case failed
        case loading
        case value([Checkpoint])
    }
    
    @Published var viewState: ViewState = .loading
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion()

    func initMap(name: String, address: String) {
        self.viewState = .loading
        getLocation(from: address) { coordinate in
            if let coordinate = coordinate {
                let checkpoint = Checkpoint(title: name, coordinate: coordinate)
                self.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1))
                
                var checkpoints: [Checkpoint] = []
                checkpoints.append(checkpoint)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                        self.viewState = .value(checkpoints)
                        print("Done")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.viewState = .failed
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getLocation(from address: String, completion: @escaping (_ location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?)-> Void) {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
            guard let placemarks = placemarks,
            let location = placemarks.first?.location?.coordinate else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            completion(location)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my **View**

```
struct MapView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var mapVM = MapViewModel()
    var name: String
    var address: String
    
    var body: some View {
        switch mapVM.viewState {
            case .loading:
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    ProgressView()
                }
                .onAppear() {
                    mapVM.initMap(name: name, address: address)
                }
            case .value(let checkpoints):
                VStack {
                    Map(coordinateRegion: $mapVM.region, annotationItems: checkpoints) { item in
                        MapAnnotation(coordinate: item.coordinate) {
                            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                                Image(systemName: "mappin.circle.fill")
                                    .renderingMode(.original)
                                    .font(.title)
                                Text(name)
                                    .font(.caption)
                                    .shadow(color: Color.systemBackground.opacity(0.5), radius: 1)
                                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 150)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            case .failed:
                Text("Failed")
            }
    }
    
}
```

And here is how I implemented the MapView in my MainView

```
VStack(alignment: .center) {
    MapView(name: tickerDetails.name, address: tickerDetails.hqAddress)
       .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 30, height: 220)
       .border(Color.systemGray4, cornerRadius: 10)
       .padding(.leading)
}
```

Last but not least, here are two Screenshots how its displayed in the canvas and in the simulator:

[image]

The data for the preview is coming from an local stored JSON-File. The data for the simulator is fetched from the internet. However the data is loaded correctly, because the print statement is executed in MapViewModel (and the coordinates are also correct). It's just simply not updating the view with the data.

**Edit**

I implemented the MapView in a "normal" view and it works fine there. It seems to be, that the presented sheet can't work with view states...